# Tiny function to ensure a node of a BST has a valid relationship with its children

Tags: java

I need to write a method to ensure that all of the nodes of a BST (Binary Search Tree) are valid. For a node to be valid, 2 things must hold:

- The left child must be less than the current node's value
- The right child must be greater than the current node's value.

I decided to write a helper method that checks an individual node. Conceptually, it's easy enough, but the end result looks clumsy. I started out with:

```
//Returns true if the left node is less than the current node, and the right
// node is greater than the current node.
private boolean nodeIsValid() {
    if (hasLeft() && left.compareTo(this) > 0) return false;
    if (hasRight() && right.compareTo(this) < 0) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Then I realized I could combine the 2 guards into a single check:

```
private boolean nodeIsValid2() {
    if (hasLeft() && left.compareTo(this) > 0 ||
        hasRight() && right.compareTo(this) < 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

But it seems pretty bulky still. Plus, given I'm just returning true or false based on a condition, I imagine this could be compacted down into a single statement (although I don't know if that would help readability).

Which of my two versions is more pleasant and readable?

Can the check be cleanly reduced to a single statement?

Comment: If you ever have `if (x) return true; return false;` then it can always be reduced to `return x`.  In your case since you've got  `if (x) return false; return true;` it can be reduced to  `return !x`.

Comment: The function says little about whether the node itself is valid, and more about if the node ordering is valid. `nodeIsOrdered()`? `nodePositionIsValid()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which of my two versions is more pleasant and readable?

The second is just bad as said in the comment by JK01.

It should be just

```
return !(hasLeft() && left.compareTo(this) > 0 ||
    hasRight() && right.compareTo(this) < 0);
```

and then you could use De-Morgan rule to get rid of the outer negation. However, something like

```
return (!hasLeft() || left.compareTo(this) <= 0) &&
    (!hasRight() || right.compareTo(this) >= 0);
```

has nothing to do with the idea it represents. Sticking with the original and adding braces is best:

```
private boolean nodeIsValid() {
    if (hasLeft() && left.compareTo(this) > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (hasRight() && right.compareTo(this) < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

- It's easily extensible: Just add another condition.
- It's structured: 2 simple expressions instead of a multiline monster.
- It corresponds exactly with what could go wrong.